# How to solve Git lfs will skip tracked files?

Tags: git, github

I having some trouble with the use of GIT LFS. I had some issues to add a commit to git when I added CocoaPods to my Xcode project. The error that GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB. After some research I came to the LFS library. After installing I cloned the project without CocoaPods. Added the Pod file and installed the GVRSDK Pod.

After that I did the following commands:

```
git lfs track [files that where been added by CocoaPods]
git lfs track - The tracked files where tracked
git add .
git commit -m "Added Pods to project"
git push
```

But after pushing the commit I receive the same error. Also it says: `Git LFS: (0 of 0 files, 8 skipped) 0 B / 0 B, 112.96 MB skipped.`

I have updated my git to the latest version of 2.13.0

What do I wrong or am I missing? I followed this tutorial: https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Tutorial

The complete error is:

```
Git LFS: (0 of 0 files, 7 skipped) 0 B / 0 B, 1.02 KB skipped Counting objects: 760, done. Delta compression using up to 8 threads. Compressing objects: 100% (600/600), done. Writing objects: 100% (760/760), 57.14 MiB | 73.00 KiB/s, done. Total 760 (delta 212), reused 0 (delta 0) remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (212/212), done. remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com. remote: error: Trace: 4e56dff020008a4a06c019a10618d5ab remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information. remote: error: File Pods/GVRSDK/Libraries/libGVRSDK.a is 112.96 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB To https://github.com/Caspert/RSRVR ! [remote rejected] dev -> dev (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Caspert/RSRVR'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like GitHub has a limit, even on LFS files, based on the error you're getting:  remote: error: File Pods/GVRSDK/Libraries/libGVRSDK.a is 112.96 MB

Per [GitHub's documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files/):

GitHub will warn you when pushing files larger than 50 MB. You will not be allowed to push files larger than 100 MB.

Comment: It's very strange, because I already had a project that make use of the GVRSDK pod and committing and pushing will be without any issues. Until now..

Comment: Are you sure that the other project has files bigger than 100 MB?  Maybe there's a new version of the SDK?